# Getting DropDownList To BInd the Data From The Server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am having an issue with populating my ASP DropDownList with data from the database, I am trying to use ajax and jquery, followed a tutorial but added my own data. The problem that I am having is that when the page loads the drop down list is empty, the code is below.

The Html Part

```
<div id="mainitem1" class="mainItem" style="background-color: #000">

                <div class="box" style="top: 20%; position: absolute; width: 60%; z-index: 1; height: 70%; background-color: #e8e8e8; left: 32%; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.3vw;">
                    <div id="divdistSearch" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                 <table>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td></td>
                                         <td>
                                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStates" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                         </td> 
                                     </tr>
                                 </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img id="mainitem1-image" alt="" src="/powertap/images/Background1.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px" />
                <img id="mainitem1-image1" alt="" src="/powertap/images/taps-and-text.png" style="position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0; right: 0;" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the Jquery Part, I have this in a separaet .js file, but I have linked to it, in the head section

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetStates",
    data: '{}',
    contenType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {
        var ddlStates = $("[id*=ddlStates]");
        ddlStates.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
        $.each(r.d, function () {
            ddlStates.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
      }
  });
});
```

And here is the code part it is in VB, cant figure out what I am missing.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class _Default103
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
               Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As       System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Session("isLoggedIn") Then
        price_file.Visible = False
        checkstock_icon.Visible = False
        checkstock_title.Visible = False
    End If
  End Sub

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetStates() As List(Of ListItem)
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Id, State FROM States"
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DistData").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
            Dim states As New List(Of ListItem)()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    states.Add(New ListItem() With {
                               .Value = sdr("Id").ToString(), _
                               .Text = sdr("State").ToString() _
                               })
                End While
            End Using
            con.Close()
            Return states
        End Using
    End Using
  End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any value behind using JSON in your sample. But anyway you didn't bind your drop down list in the first place. The initial bind can be added to your page load event.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As       System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If !IsPostBack//Make sure this is only filled if the page is not posted back
 GetStates();
```